# Azure-backup storage quotas

Tags: azure, azure-blob-storage, azure-backup-vault

Would like to know if there is anyway to set usage quotas for Azure backup agents ?
Without this i would need to login and check what they are on everyday, this is also in an Azure CSP subscription so spend quotas dont apply.

Comment: Could you please be more specific ? what kind of quotas ?

Comment: This would be storage quotas for backed up data from the agent, i want to know if i can set a storage quota per agent or machine for storage so if a large file gets backed up that isn't supposed to, it wont commit the data to storage.